# Laravel route questions

Tags: php, laravel

### web.php

```
Route:resource('person','PersonController');
// In Actually => Person Data Edit  route:get('person/{id}/edit','PersonController@edit');
```

---

### PersonController.php

```
public $adressInformation = '';

  public function edit($id)
  {
      $persons = Person::find($id);
      //TODO...
      $this->adressInformation = $person->ADDRESS;

  }

  public adressInformation(){

       // TO DO vs 

       return $information;
  }
```

I want to  write adressInformation via route => firstly 
  `route:get('person/{id}/edit','PersonController@edit')` worked then 
  `route:get('person/{id}/edit/adressinformation'` write data

---

#### I found a solution to the problem but can not it be this way

```
public adressInformation($id){

       // TO DO vs 

       return $information;
}
```

Comment: You have to explain the problem better in order to us to understand what's going on

Comment: Problem : route:get('person/{id}/edit/adressinformation' edit function worked then adressinformation work

Answer (score 1):

You always should defining your custom route before resource route:

```
Route:get('person/{id}/edit/adressinformation','PersonController@adressInformation');

Route:resource('person','PersonController');
```